# React router: how to get rid of extra symbols added to the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am using `react-router` and passing param in the route like this:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/home/item/:item" component={Main} >
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
     <Route path="signing" component={Signin} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

However when navigating to the signing page extra symbols `+` and `%20` added to the `:item`

```
http://localhost:3000/home/item/item1%20+%20/signin
```

And if i tried to get the `:item` value using `this.props.params.item` I get  `item1 +` when i want to get only the item value in this case `item1`

Comment: How do you get this url? by clicking a link or redirection or something else?

Comment: yes, using `<Link>`, please check my answer below. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

`React Router` is not *adding* these symbols.  Check the piece of your code that is causing the navigation.

Answer (score 1):

it's not an issue about `react-router` it's my own fault when linking to signing page like this:

```
<Link to={`${currentRoutes} + /signin`}></Link>
```

when it should be like this:

```
<Link to={`${currentRoutes}/signin`}</Link>
```